# Cassandra repairs on TWCS

Tags: cassandra

We have a 13 nodes Cassandra cluster (version 3.10) with RP 2 and read/write consistency of 1.
This means that the cluster isn't fully consistent, but eventually consistent. We chose this setup to speed up the performance, and we can tolerate a few seconds of inconsistency.

The tables are set with TWCS with read-repair disabled, and we don't run full repairs on them

However, we've discovered that some entries of the data are replicated only once, and not twice, which means that when the not-updated node is queried it fails to retrieve the data.

My first question is how could this happen? Shouldn't Cassandra replicate all the data?

Now if we choose to perform repairs, it will create overlapping tombstones, therefore they won't be deleted when their time is up. I'm aware of the `unchecked_tombstone_compaction` property to ignore the overlap, but I feel like it's a bad approach. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So you've obviously made some deliberate choices regarding your client CL. You've opted to potentially sacrifice consistency for speed. You have achieved your goals, but you assumed that data would always make it to all of the other nodes in the cluster that it belongs. There are no guarantees of that, as you have found out.  How could that happen? There are multiple reasons I'm sure, some of which include: networking/issues, hardware overload (I/O, CPU, etc. - which can cause dropped mutations), cassandra/dse being unavailable for whatever reasons, etc.

If none of your nodes have not been "off-line" for at least a few hours (whether it be dse or the host being unavailable), I'm guessing your nodes are dropping mutations, and I would check two things:
1) nodetool tpstats
2) Look through your cassandra logs 
For DSE: cat /var/log/cassandra/system.log | grep -i mutation | grep -i drop (and debug.log as well)

I'm guessing you're probably dropping mutations, and the cassandra logs and tpstats will record this (tpstats will only show you since last cassandra/dse restart). If you are dropping mutations, you'll have to try to understand why - typically some sort of load pressure causing it.

I have scheduled 1-second vmstat output that spools to a log continuously with log rotation so I can go back and check a few things out if our nodes start "mis-behaving". It could help.

That's where I would start. Either way, your decision to use read/write CL=1 has put you in this spot. You may want to reconsider that approach.

Answer (score 0):

Consistency level=1 can create a problem sometimes due to many reasons like if data is not replicating to the cluster properly due to mutations or cluster/node overload or high CPU or high I/O or network problem so in this case you can suffer data inconsistency however read repair handles this problem some times if it is enabled. you can go with manual repair to ensure consistency of the cluster but you can get some zombie data too for your case.

I think, to avoid this kind of issue you should consider CL at least Quorum for write or you should run manual repair within GC_grace_period(default is 10 days) for all the tables in the cluster.
Also, you can use incremental repair so that Cassandra run repair in background for chunk of data. For more details you can refer below link

http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/repair.html or https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/tools/toolsRepair.html